# Recursively returning collection or element in collection

Tags: java, recursion, groovy, closures, static-typing

This is a simple recursive algorithm for generating a nested list from the leaves of a tree:

```
/** Make a list from bottom level of equal path tree - list would be nested according
    to hierarchy in tree.

     1
    /  \
   2    3
   /\   |
  4  5  6
    ==>
    [[4, 5], 6]
 */
List leavesToList(TreeNode node) {
    List<TreeNode> children = node.getChildren()
    if (!children) {
        return node.getData() // Problem with static typing!!
    }
    if (children.size() == 1) {
        return leavesToList(children[0])
    }
    return children.collect {leavesToList(it)}
}
```

The algorithm works fine with dynamic typing, but static typing causes problem as non-list
values cannot be returned by the function. Ideally for this case the return value
would be of type `Collection<T>|T` but such type specification is not possible.

As a work-aroud I thought of a wrapper solution like so:

```
@CompileStatic
static List leavesToList(Tnode rnode) {
    Closure inner
    inner = { Tnode node ->
        List<Tnode> children = node.getChildren()
        if (!children) {
            return node.getData()
        }
        if (children.size() == 1) {
            return inner.call(children[0])
        }
        return children.collect { inner.call(it) }
    }
    return inner.call(rnode) as List
}
```

Questions:

- Is the wrapper implementation any less efficient than the original?
  For example, is there repeat overhead for setting up closures?
- As a general technique (and not a trick specific to the example case), is there
  a better way to handle this situation, other than using a wrapper?

Answer (score 2):

I hope I'm not missing something here but for the sake of static typing I'd do something like this:

```
@CompileStatic
List leavesToList(TreeNode node) {
   List<TreeNode> children = node.children
   if (!children) {
      return [node.data]
   }
   if (children.size() == 1) {
      return leavesToList(children.first())
   }
   children.collect this.&leavesToList
}
```

basically wrapping the `data` into a list.

Comment: The output of your code is different from what's asked for by the question.